# Openlayers GetFeatureInfo not working all zoom levels

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo, ajax

I am sending **GetFeatureInfo** request to wms service. My parameter is like this. When I click to map, map click event is firing and I am sending this request to server.

```
    var params = {
            REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
            EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
            BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
            SERVICE: "WMS",
            VERSION: "1.1.1",
            X: e.xy.x,
            Y: e.xy.y,
            INFO_FORMAT: 'text/javascript',
            QUERY_LAYERS: layers_on,
            FEATURE_COUNT: 1,
            Layers: layers_on,
            Styles: '',
            WIDTH: map.size.w,
            HEIGHT: map.size.h,
            format: format,
            srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};
```

My map has 10 zoom level. In zoom level-1 is working but zoom level 10 is not working. No error message occuring.

Comment: Do you know which WMS server you are querying? Have you tested the same server with QGIS? No error messages usually means that server just does not find anything from the clicked place for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. My layers are created with sql view. When I zoom in level 10 other layers are appearing and one of them is duplicated column name. I get wms request result error like this:

**Rendering process failed↵java.io.IOException↵null↵ERROR: column reference "name" is ambiguous↵  Position: 117**